# Trouble with size classes in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, size-classes

I'm meeting a very strange problem with size classes:

- In the size class any x any, I have a `UITableViewController` that contains a `UIView` with constraint width 150 and constraint height 150.
- In the size class Regular x Regular, I "uninstall" these constraint, and I added another constraint width & height, with the size 250.

When I launch my app on iPad, I can see the "correct" size of this `UIView`, but in my code, in `ViewDidLoad`, and `ViewWillAppear`, the size of this view is still "150". (I want to get the size of my view for few things.) Only in the function `ViewDidAppear` I've the correct size, but I don't understand why.

Any ideas?

Example code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadImg];
    [self loadText];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) loadText {
    //
 }

- (void) loadImg {    
    self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = self.myView.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.myView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    UIView *svg = [Utils defineImg:self.myView :@"myImage" :50];
    [self.myView addSubview: svg];
    svg.center = CGPointMake(self.myView.frame.size.width / 2, self.myView.frame.size.height / 2);
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, using a Custom UIImageView in the method setNeedsDisplay, I'm changing the cornerRadius, but for this I need the frame's width. And I'm getting the wrong size. I'm using Size Classes in Interface Builder, btw

Comment: You can see m'y last topic about it, there is a "solution" (really not the best but it works.)

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are not correct places to look for specific frame dimensions. Frame will be set after auto-layout is complete.

You can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and get it there.

Comment: mhh okay, but I don't understand why I have the size of my view in the Any x Any size class in ViewDidLoad instead of the size of my view in the Regular x Regular... whereas on the screen of my ipad it's correct...

Comment: And it doesn't work... in viewDidLayoutSubviews, I 've again 150 x 150 instead of 300 x 300.... It seems I've the correct size only in viewDidAppear, I don't understand what happens...

Comment: Can you post code for your view controller? You might have some typos there. It must work in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I just set a log : NSLog("size : %f - %f ", self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.bounds.size.width"); and I see "150" instead of "250" :/

Comment: post edited :) So I tried to put "[self loadImg];" in viewdidlayout etc..; WITH the previous Log, and nothing works... only in viewdidappear.

Comment: Have you tried to putting it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: It's not in the code you posted. Can you post a code when you tried to do that?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    NSLog("size : %f - %f ", self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.bounds.size.width);
    [self loadImg];
} Nothing special...

Comment: Ok, I found something, but I don't know where is the difference... It works with a UIViewCOntroller, but I'm using tableviewcontroller (mistake in my post, sorry)...

Answer (score 0):

So I think you have a bit of confusion regarding the size classes.  It's the same bit of confusion I had.

When you choose to view the size class as RegularxRegular, you're just viewing what it will look like in that mode.  Any changes you make there don't override the anyxany mode.

And you should probably not constrain a width and a height on your view.  Try using constraints in relation to other views to get your UIView to look like it should on the screen.

Comment: Yes i know that. But I added specific contraint for the size class Regular x Regular... I don't understand why I see the "correct" size of this view on the iPad, but in my code, I have the size of the AnyxANy size classe :/

Comment: What do you mean by RegularxRegular won't override AnyxAny...isn't that the point?